# Want to put same value in whole column in HTML-PHP table

Tags: php, html

I want to put same value in one column in whole table.

The table looks like this
[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynesw.png)
For suppose, I want to put status as Community owner for all Lvl7's.

Here's the table code,

```
<table class="table" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="header">
            <th width="60%"></th>
            <th width="20%"></th>
            <th width="20%"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <?php
        $query = $config->prepare("SELECT playerName, playerLevel FROM `playerdata` WHERE playerLevel = 7 ORDER BY playerName DESC");
        $query->execute();                        
        while($data = $query->fetch())
        {
            echo "<tr><td>".$data['playerName']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$data['playerLevel']."</td></tr>";
        }

    ?>
</table>
```

How do I put the value as community owner for this table.
I have same tables like these for all levels.

I dont know how to echo the third column using  and  or print the same value for all rows in Status column.
When I tried to code, it only printed the value Community Owner to the last row of table.

P.S:- I am rookie in all this stuff, any type of help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello , for Status value, where it is ?  Is it in the Database ? Because you don't select it at your query ? Can you explain more where did you want to get Status value ?

Comment: Nope it is not inside database, I tried using switch statement but since I used while statement for giving values such as playername and playerlevel I cant really use the statement.

I need to manually write the status like using foreach statement or something like that.

Comment: sorry to be late, you got my answer, it will work, but i suggest to save all informations into DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($data = $query->fetch())
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$data['playerName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data['playerLevel']."</td>";
    switch ($data['playerLevel']) 
    {
        case 7:
        echo "<td>Community owner</td></tr>";
        break;

        default:
        echo "<td>Not defined</td></tr>";
        break;
    }
}
```

//Changed data['playerLevel'] to $data['playerLevel'] from the original post in switch statement, it worked :D

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used switch statement but, I used it in a different way, I did not mention $data so it was only showing default case.